# tomar datos de un archivo txt y procesar en php

Tags: php

hola chicos disculpel si no me explico bien( no soy programador), espero que me puedan ayudar con esto:
tengo un archivo .txt que se actualiza todos los dias que contien algo como esto:

---

```
canal 122       
20:30   Handball: Paris-SG vs Nantes    (FR)
2:00    NBA: Cleveland Cavaliers vs Los Angeles Lakers  (FR)

canal 123       
20:45   Rugby: Pau vs Agen  (FR)

canal 124       
2:30    NFL: Indianapolis Colts vs Denver Broncos   (FR)

canal 130       
20:00   World Championship Darts    (ENG)
2:30    NFL: Indianapolis Colts vs Denver Broncos   (ENG)
```

---

donde canal xxx  es un canal de tv y debajo aparece la programacion de ese canal.
que necesito hacer que al leer el archivo, el codigo php me ponga al lado de cada programacion el canal que corresponde; ejemplo

---

```
canal 122 20:30 Handball: Paris-SG vs Nantes    (FR)
canal 122 2:00  NBA: Cleveland Cavaliers vs Los Angeles Lakers  (FR)


canal 123 20:45 Rugby: Pau vs Agen  (FR)


canal 124 2:30  NFL: Indianapolis Colts vs Denver Broncos   (FR)


canal 130 20:00 World Championship Darts    (ENG)
canal 130 2:30  NFL: Indianapolis Colts vs Denver Broncos   (ENG)
```

espero haberme dado a entender y me ayuden con el código, de antemano gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Intentos?, ¿algún código con el que estés trabajando?, es dificil (aunque posible) que alguien te realice el código completo, debes proporcionar ejemplos de tus intentos etc. No obstante, una manera de hacerlo posiblemente sea con `expresiones regulares`, donde se detecte "canal `INT`" y borre/remplace el salto de línea a continuación de esa cadena.

Comment: ¿Es necesario que lo hagas en PHP? Si no tienes experiencia en programación podrias tratar el fichero de otras formas .... Por ejemplo un CRON que lance un script sencillo que recorra el fichero linea a linea y genere HTML puro como resultado...